# What issues if any have people had with TFS 2008?

Tags: tfs, installation

We are just about to implement full blown TFS 2008 across our development team and I'd like to find out if there are any gotchas to b e aware fo or any installation issues I am likley to face. I have Googled all the obvious places and read the anti-panic blurb on the MS sites.

Currently we have ClearQuest, SourceSafe and Final Builder. It's my understanding that all of these can go once we implement TFS. If that's true it sounds pretty good already!

Comment: Worth also asking this question on server fault. TFS administrators who are not developers are likely to be on SF rather than here SO.

Comment: @Richard: Good idea, will do so now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I had was in setting security. I needed to lock down a branch to read-only for almost everyone. So I removed all the existing entries and then accidentally hit OK. This meant no-one -- including server and project admins -- had any access. Including no one having the rights to fix it.

Turns out there is a work around, and knowing the server admins helped. A local administrator on the TFS data tier server bypasses the TFS security, and could reset the permissions.

Did cause a few minutes of panic...

Comment: @Richard: Bl00dy hell that's some gotcha. More like a DOS attack! Many thanks for that one Rich.

Comment: After that I ensured only people I really trusted had any ability to control security.

Answer (score 1):

We have some slight problems when checking in with the Visual Studio integration, it happens quite rarely but can be somewhat annoying. The VS plugin seems to think it's checked in stuff, but it really hasn't. Usually it can be resolved by checking out everything then checking it in again, and you can do it with the Explorer plugin as well if you need to be really sure it works.

We don't use the bug tracking and Wiki features in TFS, but rather JIRA and Confluence, as the functionality TFS provided didn't quite suit us.

Comment: @Skurmedel: Thanks, do you have a large team? We are only 4 permanent devs plus 4 contractors.

Comment: Haha, no we are like two - three developers.

Comment: How did oyu find TFS for a small team them it's geared more towards enterprise level teams isn't it? That's my main concern so far, do we need a TFS administrator dedicated or can it be shared amongst devs?

Comment: I'm not the TFS administrator on the team I'm part of, but we only have one and it works well. I like it, the build agents and version checking works well. We could probably use something like subversion but TFS has very good integration into existing programs (VS, Office 2007 through Sharepoint etc.)